# Tricky integer overflow when porting C to C#

Tags: c#, c, math, integer-overflow

I'm porting following C code from disassembled x86 binary:

```
(unsigned __int16) ~ (_WORD) crc32 ^ length * ~crc32;
```

This is my ported code in C#:

```
(uint) (~(ushort) crc32) ^ length * ~crc32)
```

And below there is table with some calculated values.

```
Expected   | Actual (C#)
-----------+------------
0x1082B9CB | 0x6082B9CB
0x30389AF7 | 0x20389AF7
0xD0EF1CD6 | 0xE0EF1CD6
```

As you can see, last three bytes are correct. Just the first byte is little shifted, but I can't see any pattern how it differs one from another.

Any ideas how to fix my C# code so it gives expected output?

---

Example values (C# syntax):

```
uint crc32 = 0x7601A9C5;
int length = 17;
```

They should evaluate to `0xD0EF1CD6`, but give `0xE0EF1CD6` instead.

---

Edit:
I probably forgot to mention an important thing. The output is represented as underlying raw bytes in hexadecimal notation.

Working code example: https://ideone.com/Z8eONJ

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(checksum)));
```

Comment: Can you give example values for `crc32` and `length` that should make your expected values?

Comment: It appears your casts are backwards.  `_WORD -> uint`, `__int16->ushort`

Comment: @RobertMcKee: I thought that __int16 and ushort are equal in C#? Isn't it true? I added example values, so if you think it helps, please add an answer.

Comment: __int16 sounds like it's just `short` in C# (i.e. signed). You're using some weird non-standard typedefs though, so I've no idea.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: `_WORD` is [`an unknown type; the only known info is its size: 2 bytes`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml).

Comment: `(ushort) (~(uint) crc32) ^ length * ~crc32)` I think is correct.

Comment: @cremno WORD is a varying length datatype.  It's the processing size of the processor. If compiled on a 16-bit machine, it'll be 2 bytes, if compiled on a 32-bit machine, it'll be 4-bytes.  IMHO, a very bad datatype to use in most cases.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, but casting everything to short makes it only 2 bytes long (16 bit). Expected output is 4 bytes long (32 bit). In this case, _DWORD is guessed type because I used decompiler to generate this C code.

Comment: Your example actually evaluates to 0x9D61CEFE0.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: `WORD` means 2 bytes (16 bits) in the Windows/Intel world. The OP has most likely used IDA+HexRays and I've posted a link to its definition.

Comment: `(unsigned __int16) ~ (_WORD) crc32 ^ length * ~crc32;` casting and ~ has the same precedence, therefore the cast to `_WORD` is unnecessary

Comment: @stil that isn't casting the entire thing, it's only casting the first part.`(uint) (~(ushort) crc32) ^ length * ~crc32` is the same as `((uint) (~(ushort) crc32)) ^ length * ~crc32`

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I edited my question and added working online code snippet.

Comment: Here is a working code sample in C: https://ideone.com/pKYKzl which gives the same answer as the C# one does, and not what you say is the "Expected Value".

Comment: How did you get those expected values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with CRC32 implementation. It appears that binary I disassembled didn't negate the return value, which is usually the case in most CRC32 implementations.

```
public static class Crc32
{
    private static readonly uint[] _table =
    {
        0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba,
        0x076dc419, 0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3,
        ...
    };

    public static uint ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var crc = 0xffffffff;
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            var t = bytes[i];
            var index = (byte) ((crc & 0xff) ^ t);
            crc = (crc >> 8) ^ _table[index];
        }
        return ~crc; // or maybe return crc;
    }
}
```

Therefore, the code:

```
(uint) (~(ushort) crc32) ^ length * ~crc32)
```

simplified to just:

```
(uint) ((ushort) crc32) ^ length * crc32)
```

And now it returns expected output.
It took me longer than I'm willing to admit...